# How does one append an array of known shape column by column in Python?

Tags: python, loops, storing-data

I was wondering how in Python, one can append an array of known shape column by column, where the second column is some data added to the first column.

For example in the code,

```
goalsfor = np.zeros((20,2))
goalsscored = list(zip(teamlist,goalsfor))

for i in newfixturelist[0:2]:
    hgoals = (info["HOMETEAM_TEAM1"] == i[0]) & (info["AWAYTEAM_TEAM2"] == 
    i[1]) & (info['TEAM'] == i[0]) & ((info['OUTCOME'] == "-"))
    agoals = (info["HOMETEAM_TEAM1"] == i[0]) & (info["AWAYTEAM_TEAM2"] == 
    i[1]) & (info['TEAM'] == i[1]) & ((info['OUTCOME'] == "-"))    

hg = sum(hgoals)
ag = sum(agoals)
```

Teamlist is,

```
['AFC Bournemouth',
 'Arsenal',
 'Brighton & Hove Albion',
 'Burnley',
 'Chelsea',
 'Crystal Palace',
 'Everton',
 'Huddersfield Town',
 'Leicester City',
 'Liverpool',
 'Manchester City',
 'Manchester United',
 'Newcastle United',
 'Southampton',
 'Stoke City',
 'Swansea City',
 'Tottenham Hotspur',
 'Watford',
 'West Bromwich Albion',
 'West Ham United']
```

Also, newfixturelist[0:2] is:

```
[['Arsenal', 'Leicester City'], ['Crystal Palace', 'Huddersfield Town']]
```

and the scores of the two games are

```
[[4, 3], [0, 3]]
```

respectively.

I have been trying to perform a loop that gets me the following output that stores the goals scored for each team.

```
['AFC Bournemouth', 0, 0
 'Arsenal', 4, 4
 'Brighton & Hove Albion', 0, 0
 'Burnley', 0, 0
 'Chelsea', 0, 0
 'Crystal Palace', 0, 0
 'Everton', 0, 0
 'Huddersfield Town', 0, 3
 'Leicester City', 3, 3
 'Liverpool', 0, 0
 'Manchester City', 0, 0
 'Manchester United', 0, 0
 'Newcastle United', 0, 0
 'Southampton', 0, 0
 'Stoke City', 0, 0
 'Swansea City', 0, 0
 'Tottenham Hotspur', 0, 0
 'Watford', 0, 0
 'West Bromwich Albion', 0, 0
 'West Ham United'] , 0, 0
```

My final output is hopefully to have all 380 games against the 20 teams in a 20 x 380 array so I can easily see how the goals scored by each team changes after each match.

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you :)

Comment: why Arsenal away goals is also 4? 
Have you checked hstack?
    >>> a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
    >>> b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])

Comment: sorry i don't think i made that part clear.  The columns represent the number of goals that each team has scored after each match.  For example, after the first match, Arsenal vs Leicester that finishes 4-3, Arsenal have 4 goals and Leicester have 3 goals.  After the second match, Crystal Palace vs Huddersfield that finishes 0-3, Arsenal has still scored 4 goals and Leicester 3 goals this season hence why the numbers are the same in the next column. The aim is to achieve this for 380 games.  I have not checked hstack. I will do that, thank you for your help.